# Is there a way to remove debugger & console.log statements from js files when doing a release build in Visual studio 2019?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In .Net MVC project I need to remove all the debugger and console.log statements from js files when I do a release build, I don't want to do that manually each and every time is there a way to automate this ?

**Update**

I thought of a workaround like encapsulating those statements inside a function and enabling it in debug mode only but using this function will not be mandatory which means that the code may sill have debugger and console log statements, any Ideas  :

```
  function setDebugger()
    {
        if (debugMode) {
            debugger;
        }
    }
    
    function consoleLog(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the regEx replace option in your editor for removing the console log and debugger.

RegEx for your requirement

```
(debugger;|console.log(.*);)
```

[image]

In the search text part enter the above reg ex and select the regex search option by clicking the **.*** option at the end of the text area, **empty** data on Replace text, and files to include as ***.js**

Or

Put this at the top of the file:

```
    var console = {}; 
console.log = function(){};
```

For some browsers and minifiers, you may need to apply this onto the window object.

```
window.console = console;
```